# Alarm action definition in ec2_metric_alarm ansible module

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am trying to set up an cloud watch alarm witch ansible `ec2_metric_alarm` module and I do not know how to set it to send an email on alarm

The code is

```yaml
- name: add alarm
  ec2_metric_alarm:
    state: present
    region: eu-west-1
    name: "LoadAverage"
    metric: "LoadAverage"
    statistic: Average
    comparison: ">"
    threshold: 3.0
    evaluation_periods: 3
    period: 60
    unit: "None"
    description: "Load Average"
    dimensions: {'Role':{{itme[0]}}, Node:{{item[1]}} }
    alarm_actions: ["action1","action2"]
```

What is the syntax or what do I do to express that I want it to send emails on in `alarm_actions`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The documentation is crappy for this one:
http://docs.ansible.com/ec2_metric_alarm_module.html

Here is what I would try based on boto:
http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/cloudwatch.html#module-boto.ec2.cloudwatch.alarm

**alarm_actions (list of strs) – A list of the ARNs of the actions to take in ALARM state**

The current supported ARNS are SNS topics or autoscalling policies.

In your case:
You need to **create an SNS topic** and **subscribe your email address** to that topic (also confirm the subscription) and after that **put the SNS topic ARN as a string in the alarm_actions** param that you pass to the ansible ec2_metric_alarm_module.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Mircea's answer regarding the documentation and its quality.  I personally found the solution to the same/similar problem by creating the alarm through the UI with the desired alert action and then using the AWS CLI to extract the alarm string for use with ansible

```
aws cloudwatch describe-alarms
```

In the result you can then find the action string:

```
ALARMACTIONS    arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:**Cust Account ID Here**:NotifyMe
ALARMACTIONS    arn:aws:swf:us-east-1:**Cust Account ID Here**:action/actions/AWS_EC2.InstanceId.Stop/1.0
```

In my case I had two actions, one to email me and the other to Stop the EC2 instance

These values can then be used in your ansible task:

```
alarm_actions: ["arn:aws:swf:{{ aws_region }}:{{ aws_cust_account_id }}:action/actions/AWS_EC2.InstanceId.Stop/1.0", "arn:aws:sns:{{ aws_region }}:{{ aws_cust_account_id }}:NotifyMe"]
```