# How to schedule restart/termination of instance with Ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am having difficulties creating EC2 action in `ec2_metric_alarm` module. This is an example:

```
- name: create alarm
  ec2_metric_alarm:
    state: present
    region: ap-southeast-2
    name: "cpu-low"
    metric: "CPUUtilization"
    namespace: "AWS/EC2"
    statistic: Average
    comparison: "<="
    threshold: 5.0
    period: 300
    evaluation_periods: 3
    unit: "Percent"
    description: "This will alarm when a bamboo slave's cpu usage average is lower than 5% for 15 minutes "
    dimensions: {'InstanceId':'i-1234'}
    alarm_actions: "action?"
```

I can make an e-mail notification with string like this: `arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:<account>:MyTopic`, but no idea how to build EC2 action string, for termination, restart, stop.

Comment: EC2 actions are not supported? The only way to do is from Amazon Web console?

Answer (score 1):

It is not very well documented in Ansible, but looking at the `put-metric-alarm` [CLI command documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/put-metric-alarm.html#options) there actually is a way to pass the desired EC2 action.

Each action has its own predefined ARN (values for use with IAM roles are different, check documentation):

- `arn:aws:automate:*region*:ec2:stop`
- `arn:aws:automate:*region*:ec2:terminate`
- `arn:aws:automate:*region*:ec2:recover`
- `arn:aws:automate:*region*:ec2:reboot`

Here is an example that sends a notification to an SNS topic and restarts the instance:

```yaml
- name: Create an alarm to notify about a failed instance
  community.aws.ec2_metric_alarm:
    state: present
    region: us‑east‑1
    name: "status-check-failed-alarm"
    metric: "StatusCheckFailed"
    namespace: "AWS/EC2"
    statistic: "Minimum"
    comparison: "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
    threshold: 1.0
    period: 60
    evaluation_periods: 2
    unit: "Count"
    description: "This will notify about a failed instance"
    dimensions: {"InstanceId":"i-0123456789abcdef"}
    alarm_actions: [
      "arn:aws:sns:us‑east‑1:112233445566:server-check-failed-alarm-sns",
      "arn:aws:automate:us‑east‑1:ec2:reboot"
    ]
```

Comment: The list of predefined ARN values is exactly what I needed. The ARN actions correspond to the EC2 actions that can be chosen when manually updating. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Supported EC2 actions are: SNS and autoscaling.

[Alarm action definition in ec2_metric_alarm ansible module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295711/alarm-action-definition-in-ec2-metric-alarm-ansible-module)

alarm_actions (list of strs) – A list of the ARNs of the actions to take in ALARM state

The current supported ARNS are SNS topics or autoscaling policies.